# how to run an appended data via jQuery in a PHP while loop?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

ill try my best to explain my issue very clearly, ive been working with ajax and im having some troubles appending data inside a `while` loop using jquery.

this is my loop that displays the title of the post and checks if the title has any comments. if non, it will just show no comments

```
<ul class="title">
<?php $result = getTitles();
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
      <li> <?php echo $row['title']; ?>  </li>
        <ul class="comments">
           <?php $comments = getComments();
                while (...) { ?>
           <li> <?php //get comments associated to the title posts ?>
           <?php } ?>
        <input box>
        </ul>
<?php  } ?>
</ul>
```

so it displays like this

```
title 1
  |- comment 1
  |- comment 2
  |- <input> box

title 2
  |- comment 1
  |- <input> box

title 3
  |- <b>no comment </b>
  |- <input> box
```

then i have this jQuery that fetches the value from a `<textarea id="title">` and append the result into `<ul class="title">`

```
/* AJAX - submit status */
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
        var title= $('#title').val().trim();
        if (title.length == 0 ) { //some code } 

        $.post('insert_post.php', {title: title});
        $("<li>" + title + "</li>").prependTo('.title');

    });
});
```

currently, when i append the data, it justs posts the `title` without running it inside my `while` loop.

the way i wanted it to happen is, to run the appended data inside the loop, so when being displayed, it will included all the necessary elements associated to my `while` loop

one of the elements are the `<input>` box, each title has their own `<input>` box. in the case of appended data via jQuery, it only posts the `title` and not the elements that must be included for every `title`

Comment: You do know what PHP is a server-side language, while JS is a client-side language, right? Basically, you can't run a JS script in a PHP while loop. In addition, your markup is invalid — you have nested a `<ul>` and `<input>` element in the `<ul class="title">`. The only valid children of `<ul>` elements are `<li>`.

Comment: sorry, if my explanations were a bit unclear. i just realized that theres no way i could insert the appended data into a while loop. i just thought maybe there's a way to do this in jquery. as ive just recently learned that framework.

Comment: Also, where exactly do you want to insert the title? You haven't made it clear, because you have two levels of nesting.

Comment: in my `<ul class="title">` thats the place where i put my title. each title has its own comments, thats why i have a sub `<ul>` where i list down my comments.

Comment: Why would yo want to prepend/append the title when it's already there?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid — the only valid children of a `<ul>` element is `<li>`, and not other elements. Reformat your HTML as follow:

```
<ul class="title">
<?php $result = getTitles();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <li title="<?php echo $row['title']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
        <ul class="comments">
        <?php $comments = getComments();
            while (...) { ?>
            <li> <?php //get comments associated to the title posts ?>
        <?php } ?>
            <li>
                <form>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php  } ?>
</ul>
```

Your DOM will look like this:

- **Title 1**

  - Comment 1
  - Comment 2
  - Input
- **Title 2**

  - Comment 1
  - Input

In order to fetch the `title` when you are doing an AJAX call, simply get the `title` attribute of the parent of the `<ul class="comments">` element:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
    // Alternate:
    // $(document).on('submit', '.comments form', function() {
        // Travel up DOM tree to get the title, from the <li> element with the title attribute specified
        var title = $(this).parents("li[title]").attr("title");

        // Do rest of the AJAX call
    });
});
```

As attached here is a barebones JSFiddle demo that you can travel up the DOM tree to search for the right title: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/jyMYY/